# Why does cudaMalloc() use pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, cuda

For example, `cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, num_bytes);`

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989039/use-of-cudamalloc-why-the-double-pointer) before, and the reply was "because `cudaMalloc` returns an error code", but I don't get it - what has a double pointer got to do with returning an error code? Why can't a simple pointer do the job?

If I write

```
cudaError_t catch_status;
catch_status = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, num_bytes);
```

the error code will be put in `catch_status`, and returning a simple pointer to the allocated GPU memory should suffice, shouldn't it?

Comment: It is a C API, there is no other way to pass pointer by reference.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In C, data can be passed to functions by value or via [simulated pass-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Overview) (i.e. by a pointer to the data).  By value is a one-way methodology, by pointer allows for two-way data flow between the function and its calling environment.

When a data item is passed to a function via the function parameter list, and the function is expected to modify the original data item so that the modified value shows up in the calling environment, the correct C method for this is to pass the data item by pointer.  In C, when we pass by pointer, we take the address of the item to be modified, creating a pointer (perhaps a pointer to a pointer in this case) and hand the address to the function.  This allows the function to modify the original item (via the pointer) in the calling environment.

Normally `malloc` returns a pointer, and we can use assignment in the calling environment to assign this returned value to the desired pointer.  In the case of `cudaMalloc`, the CUDA designers chose to use the returned value to carry an error status rather than a pointer.  Therefore the setting of the pointer in the calling environment must occur via one of the parameters passed to the function, by reference (i.e. by pointer).  Since it is a *pointer value* that we want to set, we must take the address of the pointer (creating a pointer to a pointer) and pass that address to the `cudaMalloc` function.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I got mixed up with the return value and pass by reference... thanks!

Comment: So in simple terms, you pass a pointer a to pointer to future array, because you want the method to change that _pointer_ and not an _array_ as you would usually.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Robert's answer, but to first reiterate,  it is a C API, which means it does not support **references, which would allow you to modify the value of a pointer (not just what is pointed to) inside the function**. The answer by Robert Crovella explained this. Also note that it needs to be `void` because C also does not support function overloading.

Further, when using a C API within a C++ program (but you have not stated this), it is common to wrap such a function in a template.  For example,

```
template<typename T>
cudaError_t cudaAlloc(T*& d_p, size_t elements)
{
    return cudaMalloc((void**)&d_p, elements * sizeof(T));
}
```

There are two differences with how you would call the above `cudaAlloc` function:

1. Pass the device pointer directly, without using the address-of operator (`&`) when calling it, and without casting to a `void` type.
2. The second argument `elements` is now the number of elements rather than the number of bytes.  The `sizeof` operator facilitates this.  This is arguably more intuitive to specify elements and not worry about bytes.

For example:

```
float *d = nullptr;  // floats, 4 bytes per elements
size_t N = 100;      // 100 elements

cudaError_t err = cudaAlloc(d,N);      // modifies d, input is not bytes

if (err != cudaSuccess)
    std::cerr << "Unable to allocate device memory" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess the signature of `cudaMalloc` function could be better explained by an example. It is basically assigning a buffer through a pointer to that buffer (a pointer to pointer), *like* the following method:

```
int cudaMalloc(void **memory, size_t size)
{
    int errorCode = 0;

    *memory = new char[size];

    return errorCode;
}
```

As you can see, the method takes a `memory` pointer to pointer, on which it saves the new allocated memory. It then returns the error code (in this case as an integer, but it is actually an enum).

The `cudaMalloc` function could be designed as it follows also:

```
void * cudaMalloc(size_t size, int * errorCode = nullptr)
{
    if(errorCode)
        errorCode = 0;

    char *memory = new char[size];

    return memory;
}
```

In this second case, the error code is set through a pointer implicit set to null (for the case people do not bother with the error code at all). Then the allocated memory is returned.

The first method can be used as is the actual `cudaMalloc` right now:

```
float *p;
int errorCode;
errorCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&p, sizeof(float));
```

While the second one can be used as follows:

```
float *p;
int errorCode;
p = (float *) cudaMalloc(sizeof(float), &errorCode);
```

These two methods are functionally equivalent, while they have different signatures, and the people from cuda decided to go for the first method, returning the error code and assigning the memory through a pointer, while most people say that the second method would have been a better choice.