# cudaMallocHost is failing to allocate even the smallest of memory

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm a bit of a CUDA newbie so was wondering if someone could help me out.

I read that pinning can seriously improve your programs performance and so am trying to do exactly that. I'm running my code on a GeForce GT 330 which has compute capability of 1.0.

When I run my program I get that cudaMallocHost failed to allocate memory and so I've condensed my problem down into a small example that can be seen below.

Mesh.hpp

```
#ifndef MESH_HPP_

#define MESH_HPP_


#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

#include <driver_types.h>

class Mesh{
public:
  Mesh();
  ~Mesh();  
  void pin_data();

  std::vector<size_t> _a;
  size_t* _a_pinned;

private:
  void cuda_check(cudaError_t success);
};

#endif /* MESH_HPP_ */
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include "Mesh.hpp"

Mesh::Mesh(){
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    _a.push_back(i);
  }
}

Mesh::~Mesh() {
  cudaFreeHost(_a_pinned);
}

void Mesh::pin_data() {
  size_t _a_bytes = sizeof(size_t) * _a.size();

  cuda_check(cudaMallocHost((void **)_a_pinned, _a_bytes));
  memcpy(_a_pinned, &_a[0], _a_bytes);
}

void Mesh::cuda_check(cudaError_t status) {
  if (status != cudaSuccess) {
    std::cout << "Error could not allocate memory result " << status << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "Mesh.hpp"


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
  mesh->pin_data();

  delete mesh;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run my code the output is:

'Error could not allocate memory result 11'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this line:

```
cuda_check(cudaMallocHost((void **)_a_pinned, _a_bytes));
```

to this:

```
cuda_check(cudaMallocHost((void **)&_a_pinned, _a_bytes));
```

(only change is to add the ampersand)

cudaMalloc operations expect to modify a pointer value, therefore they [must be passed the address of the pointer to modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936986/why-does-cudamalloc-use-pointer-to-pointer/12937162#12937162), not the pointer itself.

That fixed it for me.  I'm still a little puzzled by vectors of `<size_t>` but to each his or her own.

If you want, as a suggestion, in your `Mesh:cuda_check` method, you might add a line like so:

```
  std::cout << "Error could not allocate memory result " << status << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Error is: " << cudaGetErrorString(status) << std::endl; //add this line
```

Comment: Yes that fixes it thank you! I was given the code originally with vectors of size_t so haven't changed it.