# cudaMalloc first argument casting, why?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

after edition:
I wonder why the first argument of the [`cudaMalloc`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html) should be casted to `void**`
, e.g `(void**)&d_A` where `d_A` is a pointer. I don't understand the syntax but content with its use especially 
cudaError_t cudaMalloc  (   void **     devPtr,
        size_t      size
    )

Cheers

Comment: Did you actually mean `cudaMalloc`? (As pointed out in one answer: For `cudaMemcpy`, this question does not make sense...)

Comment: you are right, sorry...my question was about cudaMalloc

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12936986/681865

Comment: Your question remains unclear.  Are you asking why it needs to be cast at all, or are you asking specifically why it is required to be a double-pointer (`**`) argument?  If the first, it does not need to be cast in current versions of CUDA (try it.)  If the second, it is a duplicate as @talonmies has stated.

Answer (score 4):

There has never been the need to cast to `void**` for `cudaMemcpy`, as it takes a `void*`. You may be confusing with `cudaMalloc` which *does* take a `void**`.

The conversion from any pointer type to `void*` is implicit in C, but not in C++ where a cast is required.

Answer (score 0):

From the NVidia tutorial:

```
int main()
{
    int a[N], b[N], c[N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    // I deleted the code here, we don't need it
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

It seems that there is no need to cast the first argument of cudaMemcpy to void**. However, you may have to cast it to void*.

Comment: sorry ,i meant cudsMalloc