# Can someone explain what is this (void**) &d_in?

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing

I am recently trying to learn parallel programming in CUDA C language from https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs344/l-55120467/m-67895450

```
cudamalloc((void**) &d_in, ARRAY_BYTES);
```

Can someone please explain what is happening in (void**) &d_in. Also it would be highly appreciated if someone can give me reference to some links or tell me good books where i can learn this kind of advanced C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989039/use-of-cudamalloc-why-the-double-pointer I must say I agree on the horrible API design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does cudaMalloc() use pointer to pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936986/why-does-cudamalloc-use-pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: If you google around, you'll find plenty of resources to learn topics in C or C++ on the web.

Comment: @self. Why is it horrible? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is pure C/C++ matter. This `func(&pointer);` means that you are passing address (`&`) of the variable `pointer` which in fact could be a pointer. So if the variable pointer is declared as `int *pointer`, expression `&pointer` has type `int **` and the function has to be of type `any_type func(int **p)`

Yet, the cudaMalloc function has following type:

`cudaError_t cudaMalloc(void **d evPtr, size_t size)`.

It denotes the first argument has to be of the type `void **`. The type `void` has special importance in C/C++ and pointers to void (`void *`)  are able to point to any data type. So applying overcasting `(void **)` in your statement `cudamalloc((void**) &d_in, ARRAY_BYTES);` only overcasts the address of the pointer to special data type to the address of the pointer to the most general data type.