# Why is it necessary to cast to void** (e.g. in cudaMalloc calls)?

Tags: c, pointers, cuda, void-pointers

The `cudaMalloc()` function is [defined](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) using:

```
cudaMalloc ( 
  void ** devPtr, 
  size_t size)
```

The responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936986/why-does-cudamalloc-use-pointer-to-pointer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989039/use-of-cudamalloc-why-the-double-pointer) give good explanations for why the function should be defined to accept a pointer to a pointer.

I am less clear, however, on why we need to type cast the arguments we supply when calling the function to be type void**.  E.g. in the call to the function:

```
catch_status = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, num_bytes);
```

presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936986/why-does-cudamalloc-use-pointer-to-pointer).

As I understand it, defining a function that accepts void types is something which gives it more flexibility.  I.e. looking at the definition of the `cudaMalloc()` function, I interpret it to mean that it can accept a pointer to a pointer to any type of object.  As such, why should it be necessary to type cast `&device_array` (in the example above) when calling the function.  (this syntax of such typecasting seems very prevalent in the `cudaMalloc()` examples I see throughout the web).  As long as `&device_array` satisfies the condition that it is a "pointer to a pointer of any type of data", isn't that enough to (a) satisfy the function definition of the arguments `cudaMalloc()` accepts and (b) accomplish whatever programming objectives we have?

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not necessary.  You don't need to cast to `void **` anymore using modern CUDA versions of `cudaMalloc` -- try it and see.

Comment: It can accept a pointer to a pointer to any type of object, but `device_array` isn't a pointer to any type of object, it's a pointer to one particular type of object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting to `void**` is always wrong as this type is not a [generic pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427587/void-a-generic-pointer).

Thus when a function has a parameter of type `void**`, the only type of argument passed to it can be of type: `void**`, making any cast either wrong or unnecessary.

The correct way (ignoring error checking) of getting memory from cudaMalloc is:

```
void* mem;
cudaMalloc( &mem , num_int_bytes );
int* array = mem;

cudaMalloc( &mem , num_double_bytes );
double* floating = mem;
```

Comment: "Casting to `void**` is always wrong" - no it's not: `void *x; void *y = &x; void *z; *(void**)y = &z;`